# Performing a division of some elements in the column based on condition in R

Tags: dataframe

I am getting started in R and looking for some help I have this column extracted from a HTML page.

```
Brand_Value
200 M
400 M
2   B
5   B
150 M
```

As you see some items are in millions and some are in billions. I would like to convert all the million values to billion (i.e divide by 1000) and remove the characters `B` and `M`. At the end of it, this should look like:

```
Brand_Value
0.2
0.4
2 
5 
0.15
```

Any pointers appreciated, Thank you!.

Regards

R

Comment: Can you share some code to show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most concise workaround, but it should work if the column only contains values in millions and billions ("M" and "B"):

```
new_vector<-NA
test<-NA

for (i in 1:length(vector)) {

test <- grepl("M",vector)

if(test[i]==T) {
  new_vector[i] <- as.numeric( gsub("M", "", vector[i]) )*1000000
} else {
  new_vector[i] <- as.numeric( gsub("B", "", vector[i]) )*1000000000
}
}

new_vector
```